# Update a program directX

Tags: c++, directx, incompatibility

I'm new to stackoverflow, even though I've been here for a while (not registered) reading a lot of important and usefull things, and I'm grateful for a comunity like this!

I have a program, which uses directx 7.0c . The thing is, and you all might know, directx7.0c is quite old and there are incompatibility issues with win8. I have the program in full screen, then when I minimize and it then maximize it back sprites look quite bad, unrendered. To be more specific, the program is a client for a 2d game which loades sprites, hence when minimizing/maximizing the sprites go crazy/look bad.

I was just wondering if anyone that have done this before, could guide me (give me possible links? cant find anything good on this on the internet, or maybe I'm just a bad searcher) on how to update the program's directx version (to directx9 should be more than perfect)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Short answer: not possible. Long answer: Unless you have the source code, not possible. And even then, highly unlikely, DirectX changed pretty significantly between 7 and 9. You'd basically have to rewrite the entire rendering pipeline, which is basically the entire game engine for a 2D sprite based game. Your best bet is to run an older operating system in a Virtual Machine that supports DX7 natively.

Comment: Hmm, I do have the sources of the game. Hmm..